# Tasklets Bottom half Scheduling

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

Which scheduling algorithm is followed by Bottom half ? If one Bottom half is in execution and suppose another higher priority bottom half comes in that case what will be the behavior?

Please consider above case w.r.t to TASKLET

Comment: Is your bottom half implemented as a tasklet or as a workqueue?

Comment: It is implemented as tasklet.

Comment: Then what do you mean with "higher priority"? All tasklets have the same priority.

Comment: @CL. I think he is talking about tasklet_hi_schedule() and tasklet_schedule() for scheduling with high and normal priority.

Comment: Yes Rahul I am talking about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each CPU has queues for scheduled (high-priority and normal) tasklets.

When a CPU is about to return to user space from an interrupt or from a system call, it checks for scheduled tasklets, and executes them.
The same checks are done again after a tasklet has finished.
(If there are too many scheduled tasklets, they are not all executed at once, but moved into a kernel thread, `ksoftirqd`; but the principle stays the same.)

Therefore, a tasklet will never interrupt another tasklet, but a high-priority tasklet will be executed before any scheduled 'normal' tasklets.

Comment: FYI, conversely, a hardware interrupt (or top-half) <i>can</i>  interrupt or preempt a bottom-half routine.

Comment: @CL : Suppose on uni processor one interrupt handler has scheduled tasklet_hi_schedule() and in between when taskelet_hi_schedule ( High priority tasklets ) is in execution and another interrupt comes which in turn raised tasklet_schedule so in this case interrupted tasklet_hi_schdule tasklet will run and complete before scheduled tasklet_schedule correct ?

Comment: Yes; this is what I said in the last paragraph.